# How to sftp one server to another password protected server without interactive?

Tags: sftp

I want to `sftp` files from one server to another server and this thing I want to include in a script.
But the problem is the Destination server is a password protected server. So Password needs to be entered when the Password Prompt comes.

**If I'll include this in a script, I don't want any user interaction. It should take the password on its own. (I know the password, how can I include in the script so that it will take automatically**)

Can any one help? Googled a lot, but did not find appropriate answer. I can't make the connection password less, because I am working in a production Server. so I can't modify anything to the server. But I want my script should handle on its own. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want sounds a lot like ssh-keys. This allows you to create 'trusted' networks that don't require passwords to be entered. This also gives you added security so that you don't have a password in plain text in your script.

On source machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): [Hit Enter]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Hit Enter]
Enter same passphrase again: [Hit Enter]
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Now copy the public key to the destination server:

```
ssh-copy-id user@123.45.56.78
[OR]
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now in your script:

```
sftp -o "IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa" user@123.45.56.78
```

---

Alternatively you could do:

```
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
sshpass -p $password sftp user@123.45.56.78
```

Where:

- -s: Do not display password on screen
- -p: "Password: ": Display text message
- password: Bash variable in which your password stored

Comment: Thanks Dev, but I guess for the above commands I should be in super user mode, or administrative permission is required for these. I don't have the permission for that as I am working in production environment. So I want a way where the `sftp` command or my `script` can take the password on its own. I don't want to make any changes to the connection thing.

Comment: thoses commands can be made in user mode. you still have to provide remote password at least one.

Comment: I updated my post, but you don't need to be in superuser mode to use ssh-keys, unless your admin restricts your user from doing so. But since you log into the destination server, I'm assuming you have a valid account which you could set a key-pair up with. SSH keys are preferred for security than entering passwords.

Comment: Please accept the answer if the alternative method worked for you. Otherwise, let me know if you still have a problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi Dev, I tried the above things, upto copy public key is done. But `sftp -o "IdentityFile=/.ssh/id_rsa" user@ip_add` is notworking as I dont have permission to the `.ssh` dir present in the root directory. Also i tried with the command `sftp -o "IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa" user@ip_add`. here it is again asking for password like `Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_rsa':` . Here i have to enter password. then it is working, else not.

Comment: Unless you are 'root' you shouldn't use `/.ssh`. You should be using the path that was specified when the key was generated: `Enter file in which to save the key (/path/to/dir/.ssh/id_rsa)`. If you are seeing `Enter passphrase for key`, then you gave it a passphrase instead of just hitting `Enter` on your keyboard for NO passphrase, which is what you want.